# Error-in-Variables regression p-value?

Tags: r, regression, errors-in-variables

I ran an EIV model in r and I was wondering if there is something else besides the R-adjusted to see if the fit of the model is good?

I noticed that `eivreg` function of the `eivtools` package does not provide a p-value for the model. It just provides it for the coefficients.

Sorry if the question is a bit dumb but I am new to these type of models

Comment: What package is eivreg from?

Comment: It is from eivtools package

Comment: You should add that to the question.